# Visual proof that orthogonalization is a shear transform

Tags: linear-algebra

The orthogonalization process by Gram-Schmidt preserves the determinant ([proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3551331)). Is there a visualization or visual proof in the style 'proof without words' ? Here I mean orthogonalization without normalization.

For the simplest case of a $2 \times 2$  matrix I could imagine a geometric proof that shows that parallelogram and rectangle that are spanned by the matrix columns have same area. If the lengths of the parallelogram are $a, b$ with angle $\alpha$ then $a \cdot b \cdot \text{sin}(\alpha) =a \cdot c$ with $a,c$ the rectangle sides. 
Also for a $3 \times 3$ matrix it should be possible to demonstrate geometrically the equality of the volumes of the parallelepiped and cuboid. So the task is to show that *orthogonalization is a shear transform.*

Comment: do you understand QR factorization?  There's a middle ground in 'visualizing' the volume of a parallelpiped given by a triangular matrix -- in particular the diagonal elements only matter -- easy to convince yourself in 2d and 3d visually or with a little calculus or algebra.  Your question then reduces to $A = QR = (QD) (D^{-1}R)$ since for whatever reason you want $Q$ to not be normalized -- equivalently  $(D^{-1}R)$ has entries on the diagonal with modulus 1.  Since determinants multiply you can visualize $(QD) $ which is an orthogonal coordinate set w/ 'stretching' in each direction by $D$

Comment: Each step replaces a vector with its orthogonal rejection from the span of the vectors already processed. Relate this to the interpretation of a determinant as a (signed) volume.

Answer (score 0):

You can always pick the invertible $P$ and $P^{-1}$ matrices such that their determinant is one.

Then,

$A = P^{-1} B P \rightarrow det(A) = det(P^{-1}) \cdot det (B) \cdot det(P) = det(B) $

Comment: This is not a visual proof